# Mechanically proving element non-membership

Tags: correctness-proof, first-order-logic, proof-assistants

I'm facing a (possibly simple) problem while proving a theorem.

I need to show that under several (true) assumptions, some element is not in a set. Such assumptions are all met and there is are lemmata that can be employed to reach the conclusion. The problem comes from the fact that the lemma for doing so must be applied an arbitrary number of times.

Lemma 1: $\forall x:\big(x\in X \iff P(x) \big)$

Lemma 2: $\forall x,y : (P(x) \land Q(y) \land x\neq y) \Rightarrow qq \neq x $

Lemma 3: $\forall x : P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$

Assumption: $\vert X\vert=k \land k\ge 2 %\big(\forall x\in X.P(x)\big)$

Desired result: $qq\not\in X$

**What i tried so far:**

*Proof:*
Intuitively, it is easy to see that $qq\not\in X$ because I can choose two elements $a$ and $b$ of $X$ (they are distinct by definition), plug them in lemma 2, and get that $qq\neq a$. If we apply this idea $k$ times we get that $qq$ is not an element of $X$, hence it is not in $X$. $\Box$

When $k=2$ or bounded, this reasoning works.

**The problem:** $k$ is not known in advance and I can not mechanically apply Lemma 2 arbitrarily many times.

How can I prove this intuitive fact in a mechanical fashion? I've been (vaguely) suggested to employ a bijection but i still don't see how to do so.

Comment: Is the issue that $X$ might not be countable? Because induction will work for a finite or countably infinite $X$. (Whenever you notice "If we apply this idea $k$ times, it works", try induction.)

Comment: I will give it a try, perhaps it's simpler than i think.

Comment: In my domain of discourse $X$ is countable and finite.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Induction is not going to cut it. The inductive hyp. ceases to hold very quickly.

Comment: What is your inductive hypothesis, and what are your base case(s)?

Comment: Lemma: $\forall k:nat :\big(\vert X\vert = k \land k\ge 2 \big)\Rightarrow qq\not\in X$.
Since I must show this lemma holds during the execution of an automaton I must prove it as an invariant, so I first induct on the length of the execution. Secondly, I induct over $k$ and get:

Basis: $\vert X_1\vert=0 \land 0\ge2 \Rightarrow qq\not\in X_1$. Trivially true due to emptiness and $\lnot (0\ge2)$.

The inductive step:
$\forall j:nat : \big(\vert X_1\vert = j \land j\ge2 \Rightarrow qq\not\in X_1\big) \Rightarrow 
\big(\vert X_1\vert = j+1 \land j+1\ge2 \Rightarrow qq\not\in X_1\big)$

Comment: During the induction over the execution is also get a more general inductive hypothesis:
$\forall j:nat : \big(\vert X_0\vert = j \land j\ge 2 \big)\Rightarrow qq\not\in X_0$.
Stating that the lemma holds in the current state before the automaton transitions. Induction over $k$ is carried out by the prover on $X_1$ due to the rules of sequent calculus. The induction over $X_1$ stops working when the inductive hyp. needs to be satisfied, namely, there are situations where, legally, $\vert X\vert < 2$. The same Lemma with $k\ge0$ works better but I need $k$ to be at least 2 to close the proof.

Comment: There are several things I don't understand here. (1) What is this "execution of an automation" stuff? This is new information, right? I don't think it helps, and only complicates matters unnecessarily, so let's forget about it. (2) You need to make $k=2$ the inductive base case, since although the theorem you're trying to prove is true for $k=0$, it isn't for $k=1$. (3) I don't understand what "there are situations where, legally, $|X|<2$" means -- if $X$ can really be 1, then you're in trouble, as the theorem is not true here.

Comment: You are right, when $\vert X\vert=1$ the lemma does not hold because I can not use lemma2 and nothing stops $qq$ from being in $X$.
I will try to make $k=2$ the inductive basis and see what I get.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying again with a new statement:
$\forall k:nat : \vert X\vert=2+k \Rightarrow qq\not\in X$.

My inductive basis is $k=2$ and the basis proof goes smoothly.

The induction step becomes:
$\forall j:nat : \big(\vert X\vert = 2+j \Rightarrow qq\not\in X\big) \Rightarrow (\vert X\vert=2+j+1 \Rightarrow qq\not\in X)$

Comment: OK, now it's straightforward: Given a set $X$ with $2+j+1$ elements, remove some element $z$, leaving a set $X'$ with $2+j$ elements. We can assume inductively that $qq \notin X'$. Lemma 2 holds for $X'$, and $|X'| \ge 2$, so there exist distinct $x,y \in X'$ such that $P(x)$ and $Q(y)$ (any distinct pair will work). Now swap $x$ out for $z$ and apply Lemma 2 to obtain $qq \ne z$. $X=\{z\} \cup X'$, so $qq \notin X$.

Comment: I agree about your proof, but I will have to introduce additional lemmata to support several facts like "We can assume inductively that $qq\not\in X'$". The proof assistant is not providing me that fact for granted, it takes a demonstration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with proof assistants, but I would guess that good ones have some facility for inductive proofs. You might have to explicitly tell the proof assistant (or give it some clues) that that's what you want.

Comment: I'm currently using NASA-PVS, which obviously supports induction. Independently from the facility employing the induction (induct command vs nat_induction schema [weak or strong]) ... I'm missing the inductive hypothesis you plan to use. The first problem to solve is to identify a statement that allows to carry out that part. I doubt a lemma would do because it would become a recursive problem: prove $(\vert X\vert=2+j\Rightarrow qq\not\in X)$ in terms of itself.

Comment: The IH is the one you stated yourself. The LHS of the implication is what we are allowed to assume; the RHS is what we need to prove (typically using the LHS, possibly among other things). With that, the $k=2$ base case and the constraint that $k \ge 2$, we're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually proved the theorem in a mechanical fashion and I want to thank j_random_hacker for pointing out a proof sketch based on induction and correcting my wrong initial formal statement.

The actual (mechanical) solution did require the employment of an inductive predicate that allows the human prover to instantiate the inductive hypothesis to a set $X'$.

The employment of natural induction in a mechanized fashion seems to be insufficient for carrying out the proof. This specific problem is discussed further here: [Induction examples in PVS](https://shemesh.larc.nasa.gov/fm/pvs/LASER2011/Lecture-2/Lecture-a4.pdf), slide 23/61. A different solution suggested there is subtyping.